# How to implement in Python an adapter that can handle many input types?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have many functions that solve the same problem in different ways (different algorithms with different properties). The functions were programmed by different people, and each function accepts its input in a different format. As a simplified example, let's say that the input to all functions is a set of items.

- Function A accepts a dict, where each key is an item name and the value is the number of copies of that item.
- Function B accepts a list, where each element is simply the item name, and there is only one copy of each item.

I would like to build an adapter function, that allows the user to use both A and B with both a dict and a list. A pseudocode of the adapter could be:

```
def adapter(func:callable, input:any):
    if (input is a dict and func expects a dict):
       return func(input)
    elif (input is a list and func expects a list):
       return func(input)
    elif (input is a list and func expects a dict):
       return func({key:1 for key in list})  # convert list to dict
    elif (input is a dict and func expects a list):
       return func(list(input.keys()))  # convert dict to list
    else:
       raise TypeError
```

The problem with this pseudocode is that, for `n` input formats, `n^2` conditions are required.

Is there a more efficient way to implement such an adapter function?

Comment: I would define a standard structure for the data and create converters from other input structures to this structure and from the standard structure to the input formats required by each function.

Comment: 1. It's not many-to-many, each type pair connects to one other thing. 2. Think if you really need to do much: Dict is iterable over the keys already. So `for x in my_dict` would already iterate over keys, so I think there's no need for "input is a dict and func expects a list" case. And for "input is a list and func expects a dict" - think whether you can do that logic elsewhere maybe? 3. It's not n^2 because n=2, O(4) = O(1). Unless this here is just an example (but you didn't say that). 4. How do you expect to know what func expects? Important for trying to make those conditions or structs

Comment: @h4z3 1. OK.  2+3. As I wrote, this is just a "simplified example". There could be many more possible input formats. 4. This is a good question. One option is to use annotations, but I am not sure it is very reliable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

class FunctionInput:
    def __init__(self, inp):
        # conversions from an input type to `FunctionInput`
        if isinstance(inp, list):
            self._items = tuple(Item(value) for value in inp)
        elif isinstance(inp, dict):
            self._items = tuple(Item(value) for value in inp.keys())
        else:
            raise TypeError()
    # conversions from FunctionInput to another input type
    def to_list(self):
        return [item.value for item in self._items]
    def to_dict(self):
        return {item.value: 1 for item in self._items}

def adapter(func, inp):
    function_input = FunctionInput(inp)
    # checks on which type the function expects as input
    if (func expects a list):
        func(function_input.to_list())
    elif (func expects a dict):
        func(function_input.to_dict())
```

If you have `n` functions and `m` possible input types, you need to implement

- `m` conversions from an input type to `FunctionInput`
- `m` conversions from `FunctionInput` to another input type
- `m` checks on which type the function expects as input

With your method you instead need `n * m` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid making it quadratic by splitting the `adapter()` into two phases. Then both adapters combined can be a constant-time calculation, as long as you consider the size of the argument “constant”. (It is safer to say that it will be linear w.r.t. the size of the argument.)

A `dict` looks like a reasonable common ground, because it can represent the other data structures in a lossless manner. In addition to a `dict`, I also pass the original type around in the following snippet, to improve the conversion. (For example, a `list` to `set` conversion makes a `set` of values, not indices, whereas a `dict` to `set` conversion makes a `set` of `dict` keys, not values.)

```py
from inspect import getfullargspec
from typing import Any, Callable, Tuple

def argument_adapter(data: dict|list|set) -> Tuple[type, dict]:
  return {
    dict: lambda d: (dict, d),
    list: lambda l: (list, {k: v for k, v in enumerate(l)}),
    set:  lambda s: (set, {kv: kv for kv in s}),
  }[type(data)](data)

def function_adapter(
    func: Callable[[dict|list|set], Any]
) -> Callable[[type, dict], Any]:
  argspec = getfullargspec(func)
  return {
    dict: lambda _, d: func(d),
    list: lambda _, d: func([d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())]),
    set:  lambda t, d: func(set({dict: d.keys,
                                 list: d.values,
                                 set:  d.keys}[t]())),
  }[argspec.annotations[argspec.args[0]]]

#######################################################################
def adapter(func: Callable[[dict|list|set], Any], data: dict|list|set):
  return function_adapter(func)(*argument_adapter(data))
#######################################################################
```

There are many possible implementations. It is possible to omit the additional type information passing and only pass a `dict` (`d`) around. However, this comes at a cost for `set`s, as mentioned above. (In other words: Using `dict` keys to form a `set` will work for original types of `set` or `dict`, but yield just integer indices for a `list` original type. Using `dict` values to form a `set` will work for original types of `set` or `list`, but yield `dict` values (instead of keys) for a `dict` original type.)

Now let’s test it:

```py
def dict_f(arg: dict) -> str:
  return str(arg)
def list_f(arg: list) -> str:
  return str(arg)
def set_f(arg: set) -> str:
  return str(arg)

dict_arg = {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B'}
list_arg = ['item_A', 'item_B']
set_arg = {'element_A', 'element_B'}

for func, f_type in ((dict_f, 'dict'),
                     (list_f, 'list'),
                     (set_f, 'set')):
  for arg, a_type in ((dict_arg, 'dict'),
                      (list_arg, 'list'),
                      (set_arg, 'set')):
    print(f'How a {f_type} function sees a {a_type} argument:')
    print(f' Original: {arg}')
    print(f'Converted: {adapter(func, arg)}')
    print()
```

The output from the snippet above shows what each function will be getting from the `function_adapter(function)(*argument_adapter(arg))` conversion:

```
How a dict function sees a dict argument:
 Original: {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B'}
Converted: {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B'}

How a dict function sees a list argument:
 Original: ['item_A', 'item_B']
Converted: {0: 'item_A', 1: 'item_B'}

How a dict function sees a set argument:
 Original: {'element_A', 'element_B'}
Converted: {'element_A': 'element_A', 'element_B': 'element_B'}

How a list function sees a dict argument:
 Original: {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B'}
Converted: ['value_A', 'value_B']

How a list function sees a list argument:
 Original: ['item_A', 'item_B']
Converted: ['item_A', 'item_B']

How a list function sees a set argument:
 Original: {'element_A', 'element_B'}
Converted: ['element_A', 'element_B']

How a set function sees a dict argument:
 Original: {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B'}
Converted: {'key_B', 'key_A'}

How a set function sees a list argument:
 Original: ['item_A', 'item_B']
Converted: {'item_B', 'item_A'}

How a set function sees a set argument:
 Original: {'element_A', 'element_B'}
Converted: {'element_A', 'element_B'}
```